# attribute error method object has no attribute

Tags: django, python-3.x

Im new to Django Framework and i'm taking an online course on LinkedIn Learning. I am using a newer version of python/django so I run into some syntax problems.

my python version is 3.5.4rc1.
my django version is 1.11.4

I created a model in models.py for an inventory:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    titel = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    omschrijving = models.TextField()
    aantal = models.IntegerField()
```

This is the code in my views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import Http404

from inventory.models import Item

def index(request):
    items = Item.objects.exclude(aantal=0)
    return render (request, 'inventory/index.html', {
        'items': items,
    })
    return HttpResponse('<p>In index view</p>')

def item_detail(request, id):
    try:
        item = Item.objects.get.id=(id) #THIS ONE CAUSES PROBLEM???
    except Item.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404('Dit item bestaat niet')
    return render(request, 'inventory/item_detail.html', {
        'item': item,
    })
```

In the browser the localhost:8000 shows homepage as expected.
localhost:8000/item/1/ gives error:

```
AttributeError at /item/1/
'method' object has no attribute 'id'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/item/1/
Django Version: 1.11.4
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'method' object has no attribute 'id'
Exception Location: 
C:\Users\info_000\Desktop\django\mysite\inventory\views.py in item_detail, line 15
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 4):

```
item = Item.objects.get(id=id)
                      ^^^
# id = field_name of primary key in your model as string ('id' on default)
# id  = your local variable 'id' from function signature
```

Comment: Hello Max, thx for quick response! my cmd still prompts: SyntaxError invalid syntax. Anymore suggestions?

Comment: Shouldn't be any quotes here. `(id=id)`.

Comment: Hallo Daniel. That is what the course origianally said. But is not working either. Course uses different (older) combination of python/django.